# Flash requesting camera access locking up IE < 10

Tags: jquery, flash, strophe, candy

We're building a chatroom using Candy.js, Stophe.js and JQuery (1.10.2). We've been trying to add the ability for a user to stream video using Flash. The problem I'm trying to solve, is that whenever you try to stream - and  flash requests camera access. In IE 8 or 9, the browser locks up whenever anything is clicked on in the access request window for Flash. If you have already allowed access by setting Flash to always allow on the settings_manager06.html page, works fine. No problems. When the browser is not responding, it starts throwing "Out of stack space" in various places in the JQuery script after a minute. Also works fine in every other browser I've test with.

If I load the Flash object in a page by itself, works fine. It appears like whenever a click happens in the Flash permissions window, in IE 8/9, while there is other activity in the background, there is something colliding. Note: in order to make Stophe work in IE 8/9, I'm also doing XDomainRequest calls (the jabber server is cross domain). Seems suspiciously like a potential issue.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions/ideas to help solve this.

Comment: Which version of Flash, have you tried any older versions? Can you reproduce the problem with a simple example that you can share? Do you  explicitly display the permission dialog (using `Security.showSettings()` or just try to access the camera and let Flash display it automatically?

Comment: We have a test version up on bikerornot. You would have to create an account. Then go to /Chat/Test to see it. As for the permission dialogue, we've done both ways (native and showSettings()). Also as a note, I've tried dropping it in an IFrame with only the swobject script - same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in candy.js with Candy.View.Pane.onFocus. When the flash permission was clicked, the window focus event was fired on another object that may or may not exist and it was not handled.